# vb.net add value(int) in a value(int) in database from a combobox

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

vb.net add value(int) in a value(int) in database from a combobox

i'm trying to add vote in the database when the voter clicks the submit button, but it's not working, the vote section doesn't seem to add, looks like the query is not working

my database schema:

`| cid | cpos       | cfname | cmname | clname | cyr | cparty | votes |
 |  1  | President  | john   | ark   |   smith | 3   | glory  |       |`

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form4

Dim con As New MySqlConnection
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter
Private Sub Form4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    con.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
    Try
        con.Open()

        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cid, cfname, cmname, clname, cparty) as cid, " & _
                           "cpos, cid from candidate WHERE cpos='Vice President'"
        End With
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        With ComboBox1
            Dim dv1 = New DataView(dt, "cpos='Vice President'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
            .DisplayMember = "cid"
            .ValueMember = "cid"
            .DataSource = dv1
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsubmit.Click
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "Update candidate SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE cid = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString & "')"

    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)

    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    da.Update(dt)
    MessageBox.Show("Query Completed")
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a close parenthesys not needed at the end of your query

```
 Query = "Update candidate SET votes = votes + 1 " & _ 
         "WHERE cid = '" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString & "'"
```

If you don't swallow the exception, this error should be quite simple to notice.
Do not create empty `Try/Catch` blocks, at least print the error message caught by the exception

```
Try
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
 End Try
```

However, while in this context there is no real danger of a Sql Injection, I still suggest to use a parameterized query.

```
con.Open()
Query = "Update candidate SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE cid = @id"
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ComboBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString)
Try
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
con.Close()

' remove the subsequent lines with the adapter because they are useless
```

As a last note, are you sure the datatable field `cid` is a string? If it is a number then you need to convert the value passed here to an integer or you risk to get a datatype mismatch error.

**EDIT** With the error message in place it is obvious that the connection is closed by a previous command and thus cannot be used by the command. In this context I suggest to remove the global object that keeps the reference to the connection and ALWAYS create a connection object when needed and close it immediately after the usage. The [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) is perfect for this scenario

```
Query = "Update candidate SET votes = votes + 1 WHERE cid = @id"
Using con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=db")
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, con)
    con.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ComboBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
     End Try
 End Using
 End Using
```

Comment: still not adding in my database :(

Comment: Please add the MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) in the try/catch block and report what is the error received (if any)

Comment: the error says `the connection must be valid and open`.

Comment: Now it is simple to see where is the problem, right?

Comment: `cid` is not a string so i changed it to this one `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ComboBox1.SelectedItem(0).ToString)` and i received error `Truncated inicorrect DOUBLE value: 1 john ark smith Glory`

Comment: Try with ComboBox1.SelectedValue without adding any conversion.

Comment: still an error showing `Truncated inicorrect DOUBLE value: '1 john ark smith Glory'`

Comment: sir @Steve i changed my select query on showing combobox's database into this `.CommandText = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', cid) as cid, "` i removed the `cfname` `cmname` `clname` and `cparty` and the vote succesfully added, but my problem is, the only thing showing in my combobox is the `cid` the voter will not know who that is, is there any way i can show the names without having error?

Comment: Restore the query as before, change DisplayMember = "fullname" and ValueMember = "cid"